# How to unsquash an old commit?

Tags: git, commit, squash

I squashed a branch with a very large amount of commits (+1000) to my main branch accidentally. After that, some commits were made to some of those commits files. Now, I'd like to "unsquash" those +1000 commits.

Any ideas about how can I unsquash those commits without losing the commits made over them?

I tried reset --hard my main branch to before the squash and merge again the branch with the +1000 commits, but it didn't work because I lost the commits made after the squash. Also, if I merge main again, the squash commit would still exists and will "cover" the other commits in Git Blame

Comment: Did you delete the branch? "*After that, some commits were made to some of those commits files.*" Were the commits made to main or to the branch?

Comment: No, I didn't delete the branch

Answer (score 2):

> I squashed a branch with a very large amount of commits (+1000) to my main branch accidentally.

Before the squash, your repo looked like this:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F [main]
     \
      1 - 2 ... 1000 [branch]
```

After the squash, it looked like this...

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - SQUASH [main]
     \
      1 - 2 ... 1000 [branch]
```

...assuming you did not delete the branch.

> After that, some commits were made to some of those commits files.

Assuming you mean that you added commits to main, your repo now looks like this:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - SQUASH - G - H [main]
     \
      1 - 2 ... 1000 [branch]
```

> Any ideas about how can I unsquash those commits without losing the commits made over them?

Yes, do an interactive rebase and remove the squash commit.

Pick a commit before the squash, and then start an interactive rebase: `git rebase -i <commit>`. An editor will appear with all the commits after your chosen one. Simply delete the line with the squash, save, and exit the editor. Git will rewrite the commits after the squash (G - H) on top of the previous commit (F). See [Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for more detail on interactive commit.

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G1 - H1 [main]
     \
      1 - 2 ... 1000 [branch]
```

Then, if you already pushed main, [`git push --force-with-lease`](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/) to safely push the new branch.

---

***UPDATE*** [Comments from the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74778723/how-to-unsquash-an-old-commit/74778970?noredirect=1#comment131993007_74778970) have made it clear the situation is much more complex.

> *Let's say I have 3 merge commits after the 5 squashes [in main], and each of these 3 merge commits comes from a branch with over 1k commits. And after these 3 merge commits, main has around 50 commits with recent work.*

A branch with over 1000 commits indicates something is wrong, or very exceptional, with your process, and I encourage you to ask a question about that process.

Your repo looks something like this. I've only shown two squashes and two merges for simplicity.

```
 1 - 2 - 3 ...... 1000
/                     \
A - B - S1 - S2 - M1 - M2 - 1 ... 50 [main]
     \           /
      Z ....... Y
```

You want this.

```
 1 - 2 - 3 ...... 1000
/                     \
A - B ---------- M1 - M2 - 1 ... 50 [main]
     \           /
      Z ....... Y
```

You can do this with a rebase, being careful to preserve the merges.

```
git rebase -r --onto B S2 main
```

Where "S2" is the last squash merge you wish to delete. `-r` tells Git to preserve merge commits. This *should* work, but be prepared to undo it with `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`. See [Rebasing Merges](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_rebasing_merges) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the answser! I tried the rebase but there are too many patches (3000+) and it seems that every of them have conflicts. Also, I'd like to replace the SQUASH commit for a MERGE one. I think this would prevent having conflicts in every commit after MERGE

Comment: @VernerCodoceo None of those patches should be on the main branch. Sorry if I didn't make it clear, checkout main and then do the rebase. Or maybe I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm doing the rebase from main. Maybe the problem is that I have a large amount of commits (3000+) after SQUASH. For context purposes, I moved from a polirepo to a monorepo. After moving 5~ repos with its history to the monorepo, (accidentally) squash-merged them, and making some commits over them, I realized that my history was lost due to the squash-merge. I've tried many combinations of rebase, but every of them raise a ridiculous amount of merge conflicts. The combination that have been best so far is `git rebase -i HEAD~N --rebase-merges` and deleting the merge commit, [Continue]

Comment: [Continue] but it gave me conflicts when reaching the new commits on the monorepo (where I'm editing the files from the squash-merge).

Comment: @VernerCodoceo You have 3000 commits after the squash *in main*?! Perhaps you should ask a question about whatever process is causing that; there's probably a better way.

Comment: My bad, they are not in `main`, but they are reachable from `main`'s `HEAD`. Let's say I have 3 merge commits after the 5 squashes, and each of these 3 merge commits comes from a branch with over 1k commits. And after these 3 merge commits, `main` has around 50 commits with recent work.

Comment: @VernerCodoceo "*a branch with over 1k commits*" That seems like a problem. Again, I encourage you to ask about whatever process lead to that. I'll update the answer with a way to undo the squash.

Answer (score 2):

Copying back the diagram from [@Schwern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74778970/86072) :

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - SQUASH - G - H [main]
     \
      1 - 2 ... 1000 [branch]
```

If you run :

```
git rebase --onto 1000 SQUASH H
```

you should reach :

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - SQUASH - G - H [main]
     \
      1 - 2 ... 1000 - G1 - H1 < HEAD (detached HEAD state)
                  ^
                [branch]
```

You can then choose from several ways to update `[branch]`, one of them is:

```
git switch branch
git merge --ff-only H1
```